# strcmp conversion from ‘char’ to ‘const char*’

Tags: c++, char, strcmp

I'm having a problem with strcmp.

This is my code.

```
while (strcmp("m",wood) !=0 || strcmp("j",wood) !=0 || strcmp("o",wood) !=0){
    cout << "(m for mahogany, o for oak, or p for pine): ";
cin >> wood;
}
```

And this is my error:

```
dining.cpp: In member function ‘void DiningSet::woodType()’:
dining.cpp:76:24: error: invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘const char*’ [-fpermissive]
/usr/include/string.h:143:12: error:   initialising argument 2 of ‘int strcmp(const char*, const char*)’ [-fpermissive]
dining.cpp:76:48: error: invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘const char*’ [-fpermissive]
/usr/include/string.h:143:12: error:   initialising argument 2 of ‘int strcmp(const char*, const char*)’ [-fpermissive]
dining.cpp:76:72: error: invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘const char*’ [-fpermissive]
/usr/include/string.h:143:12: error:   initialising argument 2 of ‘int strcmp(const char*, const char*)’ [-fpermissive]
```

Comment: If you want to compare two `char`just use `==` or `!=`, if you want to compare two strings(`char *`) then use `strcmp`. It doesn't make any sense to compare a single character to a character string, which is what you seems are doing.

Comment: what's the datatype for wood..??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`wood` is of type `char`: it must be a string, ie, `char*`, to be used in `strcmp()`.

Change to:

```
while ('m' != wood && 'j' != wood && 'o' != wood)
```

Comment: This answer is correct, @Daniel D C, add to that what my comment says under the Q for better understanding.

Comment: @DanielDC I think take a look at [char and string literals](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/macxhelp/v6v81/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.vacpp6m.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fclrc02ccon.htm) in addition too the answer :)

Comment: Thanks guys ! appreciate the quick response !

Comment: char compare only use "==" and with single char include with " ' "

Answer (score 0):

The error shows problem with second argument. It should be of a `const char *`

The signature of `strcmp` is:

`int strcmp ( const char * str1, const char * str2 );`